# Passing a array of structs to a function

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I am trying to pass an array to a function of this struct:

```
struct processData
{
    int arrivalTime;
    int durationTime;
    int completionTime;
    int turnAroundTime;
    int waitTime;
    int processNumber;
    float netTurnAroundTime;
} temp;


processData a[n];

find(a);

void find(struct processData a[])
{
int tempDurationTime[n];
int flag = 0;
int count = 0;
int currentProcess;
j = 0;
int timeQuantum = 5;
...
```

I am getting a error that says no matching function call to find(processData[n]). I am not sure why I am getting this error since the function header takes struct processData a[]. 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: find is declared after the call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find(a);`
```

is actually a function call rather than a function declaration and that is why you are getting the no matching function error because you are trying to call the function before you defined/declare it.

Try this:

```
struct processData
{
    int arrivalTime;
    int durationTime;
    int completionTime;
    int turnAroundTime;
    int waitTime;
    int processNumber;
    float netTurnAroundTime;
} temp;


processData a[n];

void find(struct processData a[])
{
int tempDurationTime[n];
int flag = 0;
int count = 0;
int currentProcess;
j = 0;
int timeQuantum = 5;
...
}

int main()
{
    find(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a function before it actually defined you need use forward declaration.

Example:

```
int blah();

int g = blah();

int blah()
{
    return 9;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure function `find` is properly declared before it is called (i.e.: make sure header where the function is declared is properly included)